# Different interpretations for '<=' operator in VHDL

Tags: syntax, comparison, vhdl, variable-assignment, ambiguous

(*this part of the question has been answered in the comments*) How does the VHDL interpreter know the difference between the signal assignment operator (**<=**) and the less-than-or-equal operator (**<=**) ?

The second part of the question: I think using the same symbol for different operations makes it easy to introduce hard-to-find bugs and reduces the readability of code:

```
if signal <= '1' then -- less-than-or-equal
...
end if;

if signal = '1' then  -- equal
...
end if;

signal <= '1';        -- signal assignment
```

Is there a workaround to prevent introducing that kind of bug and improving readability? The code above will be synthesizable, but may be hard to read or not do what you expect.

Comment: There is no possibllity of introducing such a bug. "<=" isn't an assignment operator. Signal assignments are statements, all of which are terminated with a semicolon. A statement isn't part of an expression. (VHDL has no expression statements.) You'll find you're not able to demonstrate your theoretical bug.

Comment: Expressions are described in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9. Expressions, the BNF in 9.1 is normative. A condition expression used in an if statement in your theoretical example returns a boolean value (10.8 If statement). Expressions are "a formula that defines the computation of a value". "A signal assignment statement modifies the projected output waveforms contained in the drivers of one or more signals (see 14.7.2), schedules a force for one or more signals, or schedules release of one or more signals (see 14.7.3)" (10.5 Signal assignment statement).

Comment: basically you cant. <= (assignment) is not a function, and cannot be overriden. This is perfectly acceptible and can never cause compiler confusion:
a <= b <= c; -- a assinged to b lessthan or equal to c

Comment: @user1155120 
Thank you for the clarification. It was a two-part question actually.
In the second part, I was thinking about a bug I had, where I wrote
"if a <= '1' " but I actually meant "if a = '1' ". And this led me to question the choice of using the same operator with different meanings depending on the context, I think it makes the code a little bit less readable

Comment: Note the same usage of "<=" for assignment in SystemVerilog. For a declared as type std_logic condition a <= '1' would be true if a were 'U', 'X' or '0;.  The base type std_ulogic is an enumerated character type and the character literal '1' can only have an enumerated character type inferred by context (here the condition in the if statement).